# Orientação da RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

Como posso fazer para a recyclerview em vez de preencher de cima para baixo começar de baixo para cima.

**EDITADA**

quando abro minha atividade com o recyclerview e ele tem varias mensagem de modo que ultrapassa o tamanho da tela as a mensagens mais novas ficam fora da tela só aparece rolando a tela eu preciso que seja ao contrario as mensagem novas fiquem no roda pé e as mais velhas fiquem no topo da tela..

```
     @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        super.onStart();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatViewHolder> firebaseRecycleAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatViewHolder>(

                Chat.class,
                R.layout.chat_row,
                ChatViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase


        ) {
            final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ChatViewHolder viewHolder, Chat model, int position) {

                final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setComentario(model.getComentario());
                viewHolder.setFtperfil(getApplicationContext(), model.getFtperfil());
                viewHolder.setData(model.getData());


                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, post_key , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent(ActivityChat.this, ID_usuario_perfil.class);
                        singleBlogIntent.putExtra("blog_id", post_key);

                        startActivity(singleBlogIntent);


                    }
                });
            }};
    }
        });
        mChatlist.setAdapter(firebaseRecycleAdapter);

    }


    public static class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;
        ImageButton mLikebtn;
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        public ChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

            mLikebtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.like_Btn);


            mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Like");
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);

        }


        public void setName (String username) {
            RobotoTextView post_username = (RobotoTextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.nameChat);
            post_username.setText(username);


        }

        public void setComentario (String comentario) {

            TextView post_username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.messageChat);
            post_username.setText(comentario);
        }
        public void setData (String comentario) {

            TextView post_data = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dataChat);
            post_data.setText(comentario);
        }

        public void setFtperfil(Context ctx, String ftperfil) {
            CircleImageView post_perfil = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageChat);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(ftperfil).into(post_perfil);

            }
        }}
```

Comment: De repente se você mudar a ordenação da list possa resolver, em vez de querer mudar a ordenação do RecyclerView

Comment: Mude a ordenação da lista como o @GabrielLocalhost disse é a melhor solução.

Comment: ta bom como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, faça as seguintes alterações no seu RecyclerView, desconsiderando a primeira linha do bloco:

```
LinearLayoutManager layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
layout_manager.setReverseLayout(true);
layout_manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Certo entendi agora, voce quer mostrar os valores do fim

existe um metodo chamado

smoothScrollToPosition

se usa assim `lista.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`

ele vai começar a partir da posição que voce definir

se for a ultima basta gravar o valor da posição e repassar o parametro

se estiver usando recycler view por exemplo fará assim mais ou menos

```
recyclerView.smoothscrolltoposition(lista.size());
```

Como os valores durante a inserção são os ultimos logo vai direto pro fim

acho que foi isso que quis dizer

Comment: não funcionou do jeito que eu esperava, talvez seja o modo que perguntei.